# DocuSign Api - blank excel/word document throws a large exception - and returns stack trace

Tags: rest, docusignapi

During testing one of our developers has attempted to create an envelope containing a blank excel document.  This has not only caused the creation process to fail, but it also returns a fairly large stack trace via the REST api:

```
{
  "errorCode": "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document(Blank XLSX Document) to a PDF. Error: UserId:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX IPAddress:XX.XXX.XXX.XX Source:ApiRESTv2:System.InvalidOperationException: This is an operation fail: OperationFailed\r\n   at Platform.Common.Throws.InvalidOperationExceptionIf(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)\r\n   at Sandbox.Client.SandboxHostCommsTcpClient.DoSandboxOperation(String module, String method, Byte[] payload)\r\n   at Sandbox.Client.SandboxClient.DoOperation(String module, String method, Byte[] payload, Predicate`1 isSuccess, String& errorMessage)\r\nSystem.InvalidOperationException: This is an operation fail: OperationFailed\r\n   at Platform.Common.Throws.InvalidOperationExceptionIf(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)\r\n   at Sandbox.Client.SandboxHostCommsTcpClient.DoSandboxOperation(String module, String method, Byte[] payload)\r\n   at Sandbox.Client.SandboxClient.DoOperation(String module, String method, Byte[] payload, Predicate`1 isSuccess, String& errorMessage)\r\nSystem.InvalidOperationException: This is an operation fail: OperationFailed\r\n   at Platform.Common.Throws.InvalidOperationExceptionIf(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)\r\n   at Sandbox.Client.SandboxHostCommsTcpClient.DoSandboxOperation(String module, String method, Byte[] payload)\r\n   at Sandbox.Client.SandboxClient.DoOperation(String module, String method, Byte[] payload, Predicate`1 isSuccess, String& errorMessage)\r\n"
}
```

The same issue occurs with blank Word documents.  I just wondered if this was normal?  Not being able to include a blank document makes sense (*why would you need to?*) but I wouldn't expect to receive an exception with this level of detail relating to the internal workings of the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the expected behavior (not to allow a blank file), as I've received a similar error message before when attempting to add a blank (txt) file to an Envelope. If you add even a single character to either of the files that you're testing with (so that file size is no longer 0 bytes), that should eliminate the error.

That said though, the value of the **message** attribute for error I've seen in the past is simply "System was unable to convert this document to a PDF. Unable to convert Document(Blank XLSX Document) to a PDF." -- I don't believe I've ever seen the additional text that follows in the **message** you've posted.  Seems like this is likely a mistake on DocuSign's part (i.e., this info shouldn't be included in the **message** attribute value).

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kim.  I suspected as much.

Comment: Happy to help!  When you have a moment, can you please mark this as an "accepted" answer, so that others may benefit from it in the future?  Thank you.

Comment: Done - although I'm hoping that DocuSign will also respond to say if it's going to be amended... :)

Comment: submitted to DocuSign as a potential enhancement/fix.